# fullcalendar drop in add event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-draggable

I am changing my responsibilities. I use FullCalendar in my project. I also want to use the callback I use in the event in drop. In short, I want to add the event I dragged from the list into the calendar and how can I do it in drop?
Thanks in advance

Javascript;

```
 $('#m_calendar').fullCalendar({
                drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
                    jsEvent.originalEvent.preventDefault();
                    var title = jsEvent.target.dataset.title;
                    var start = jsEvent.target.dataset.start;
                    var end = jsEvent.target.dataset.end;
                    var id = jsEvent.target.dataset.id;

                    var newEvent = new Object();
                    newEvent = {
                        title: title,
                        id: id,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        objectID: 0
                    };
                    eventsAdded.push(newEvent);   

                },
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Schedule/GetCalendarEvents',
                        dataType: 'xml',
                        data: {
                            start: start.unix(),
                            end: end.unix()
                        },
                        success: function (doc) {
                            var events = [];
                            $(doc).find('event').each(function () {
                                events.push({
                                    id: $(this).attr('id'),
                                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                                    start: $(this).attr('start'),
                                    end: $(this).attr('end')
                                });
                            });
                            callback(events);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                        },
                    });
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, either

1) If you include the event data in the properties of the `draggable` that you drag onto the calendar then the event will be added to the calendar automatically when you drop it. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive for details of how to specify the data. Also see the external dragging demo at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo for a working example - you can look at the source code in the linked CodePen to see how it's done.

2) To modify your current code simply call

```
$("#m_calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", newEvent, true);
```

at the end of your "drop" callback.

This adds the new event to the calendar display. Of course if you need to add it to your database as well you'll need to make a suitable call to the server at the same time.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/renderEvent for documentation.

---

P.S. This used to be a completely different question until you edited it (see the question's edit history). In future please don't edit a question to be a new question...someone might still want to answer the previous version. Ask a completely new question instead (and delete the old one if you no longer want it). Otherwise earlier comments or answers (such as the comment I had posted on here and have now removed) will make no sense. Thanks.